flexsurvspline with offset
I am trying to use the offset function within flexsurvspline in R to force the weights of a regression coefficient to be fixed at 1.
I am using R 4.4.0 via RStudio (2024.04.0) on a Windows PC.  The code below worked on the previous version of the flexsurv but is not working since my recent update (version 2.3).
The code that was working is:
library(survival)
rfs  <- pmax(rotterdam$recur, rotterdam$death)
rfstime <- with(rotterdam, ifelse(recur==1, rtime, dtime))
fit1 <- flexsurvspline(Surv(rfstime, rfs) ~ age + meno + size + er,  k=2, data = rotterdam)
# obtain the linear predictor for each patient
predf <- model.matrix(fit1) %*% fit1$res[-(1:4),"est"]

# Predict baseline survival at 5 years
y5_Flex_1 <- summary(fit1,type="survival",t=5)
y5_Flex <- y5_Flex_1[[1]]$est
y5_Flex

# Shrinkage factor 
vanH <- 0.9589255
heuristic_lp_flex = vanH*predf      

# Now calculate the shrunken model baseline survival prob at 5 years by fixing the shrunken lp as an offset and predicting the baseline survival
fit1_shrunk <- flexsurvspline(Surv(rfstime,rfs)~offset(heuristic_lp_flex),k=2,data=rotterdam)

The error message is

Error in model.matrix.default(forms[[i]], m) :
model frame and formula mismatch in model.matrix()

Any suggestions gratefully received!!!

I cannot reproduce your error. The code works without any issues. Can you run this command and see what you get? fit1_shrunk <- flexsurv::flexsurvspline(survival::Surv(rfstime, rfs) ~ stats::offset(heuristic_lp_flex), k = 2, data = rotterdam).

Does the command I suggested work? Were you able to resolve your issue?
